# Meaning of this question?

Tags: geometry

I'm not sure what this question wants me to do:

> Derive a general rule linking the surface area of a cylinder with one of its dimensions (height or radius).

I know that the formula for the surface area of a cylinder is
$$  
\text{SA}=2\pi r^2+2\pi r h
$$
However, how am I to supposedly link in height or radius? Can anyone explain what this question wants and perhaps give me a hint as to how to go about it? I have just studied differential calculus so any solutions beyond this level o mathematics is not possible. Apologies in advance for any complications this may cause.

This question is from a differential geometry assignment. The context of the question is that we are to analyse the packaging used for tin cans and determine if their dimensions are chosen to reduce the amount of material used, hence the surface area, while maintaining the same volume. This specific part of the question involves finding a general rule to link the SA formula and one of its variables, of which the output will be used to find the dimensions that use the minimum SA via differential calculus.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to take out $r $ common. Hence you have established a relation.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN But does that link the equation with one of the dimensions?

Comment: I agree that this question seems rather unclear.  Could you maybe explain more about the context in which it was asked, which might make it clearer?

Comment: This question is from a differential geometry assignment. the context of the question is that we are to analyse the packaging used for tin cans and determine if their dimensions are chosen to reduce the amount of material used, hence the surface area. This specific part of the question involves finding a general rule to link the SA formula and one of its variables, of which the output will be used to find the dimensions that use the minimum SA via differential calculus.

Comment: Is the volume of the cylinder supposed to be determined?  If so, you could use that to write one of the dimensions in terms of the other.

Comment: Yes, however that is only to ensure that the dimensions will hold the same amount of contents as the original. The focus is to determine the least amount of material that can be used for the same volume. What you suggest would work, unfortunately that does still leave me with two variables, V and r, and I have only studied differential calculus so far, neither does the assignment allow for methods other than the ones taught during class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the volume is supposed to be fixed (as you indicated in the comments), you can use this to write one variable in terms of the other.  If $V$ is the volume (which is supposed to be just some constant), you have $V=\pi r^2h$, so you can write $h=V/\pi r^2$.  You can then substitute this into your equation to get $$SA=2\pi r^2+2V/r.$$

This is now an equation for the surface area in terms of just $r$, since $V$ is a constant.

Comment: How can you say that $V $ is a constant where $V $ is dependent on both $r$ and $h$, which are both variables? You have only changed the equation a bit.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: In the context of this problem, you are looking at different cylinders with a single fixed volume.  So $V$ is set equal to some constant in this problem.